# how to break column early by media query?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I used this code in my project.I want cards are break before its normally breakingpoint.I try the cards break when window size is 700px. but it remains same,how to do this? can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance for help :)

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--jQuery library--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .card-body {
   padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .card-content {
   padding: 1.25rem;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row my-4">
     <div class="col">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm d-flex">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                  <div class="card-header"><center>Education</center></div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                 <h5 class="card-title">● hello hello hello hello hello 2019</h5>
              <p class="card-text"><br>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ●hello hello hello hello helooo</h5>
              <p class="card-text">something...................................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ● hello hello hello hello hello</h5>
              <p class="card-text">sometthing here........................</p>
          </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           <div class="col-sm d-flex">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header"><center>Traings & Online Courses</center></div>
             <div class="card-content">
              <h5 class="card-title">TRAINING</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● .........................................................<br> ● ..............................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● blah blah blah blah..... <br>
        ●blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
       </div>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have your tried `media-query`? Give custom class to your `column` and apply css to it. In specific `media-query`

Comment: @AbdulBasit yes, I add an id in <div class="col-sm d-flex">  and apply media query to that id .but it fails. i guess i done some mistake

Comment: can you please post Jsfiddle

Comment: @AbdulBasit its here    https://jsfiddle.net/Ayan0000/qLk3jp4g/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look into this

```css
 
        .card-body {
   padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .card-content {
   padding: 1.25rem;
  }
   @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    #edu1 .card {width:700px;height:700px;background:red;}
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,700,700i" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--jQuery library--> 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--Latest compiled and minified JavaScript--> 
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .card-body {
   padding: 0 !important;
  }
  .card-content {
   padding: 1.25rem;
  }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row my-4">
     <div class="col">
         <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm d-flex " id="edu1">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                  <div class="card-header"><center>Education</center></div>
                  <div class="card-content">
                 <h5 class="card-title">● hello hello hello hello hello 2019</h5>
              <p class="card-text"><br>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ●hello hello hello hello helooo</h5>
              <p class="card-text">something...................................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title"> ● hello hello hello hello hello</h5>
              <p class="card-text">sometthing here........................</p>
          </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           <div class="col-sm d-flex" id="edu2">
               <div class="card card-body flex-fill">
                <div class="card-header"><center>Traings & Online Courses</center></div>
             <div class="card-content">
              <h5 class="card-title">TRAINING</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● .........................................................<br> ● ..............................................</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
        <p class="card-text">● blah blah blah blah..... <br>
        ●blah blah blah blah blah.</p>
        <h5 class="card-title">ONLINE COURSE 2015</h5>
       </div>
            </div>
           </div>
       </div>
         </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```